# How to get distinct values with olivere/elastic in Go

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

```
{
   "query" : {
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "aggs":{
        "geo": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "geoCurrent.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello. Request above sent from postman works ok. I need to do this query from golang to get distinct field values.
I found examples like:

```
// ec - elastic client
s := ec.Search().Index(dbName).Query(elastic.NewMatchAllQuery()).Type("_doc")
agg := elastic.NewTermsAggregation().Field("geoCurrent.keyword")
s = s.Aggregation("geo", agg)
s.Size(0)
r, err := s.Do(context.Background())
if nil != err {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}

resp, ok := r.Aggregations.Terms("geo")
if !ok {
    log.Println(ok)
    return
}

for _, res := range resp.Buckets {
    log.Println(res.Key)
}
```

But resp.Bucket is empty. Whats wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting size 0? AFAIK, it's not supported for newer elasticsearch versions: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_aggregations_changes.html#_literal_size_0_literal_on_terms_significant_terms_and_geohash_grid_aggregations. Also, you don't use it in your initial query

Comment: It was in example. Works the same without .Size(0)

Comment: Can you post generated query? If i remember it correctly, you can use `Source` method on `s` to get it. Or refer to olivere/elastic docs for that.

Comment: Queries like elastic.NewbBoolQuery() have .Source() method you talking about. This only have `func (s *SearchService) Source(source interface{}) *SearchService`
agg.Source() is available.
`{
 "terms": {
  "field": "geoCurrent.keyword"
 }
}`

Comment: I see. Then i would suggest to build `SearchSource` yourself. `Query` and `Aggregation` methods do basically that, look at source code: https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/a433ea8f2ab64dda5ec671d84015e0cd2b698b30/search.go#L202. `SearchSource` has right Source method https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/83b6b3154663f7294e3b2151b72fc7f4c64848b7/search_source.go#L366